# Monodevelop console on OS X

Tags: macos, console, terminal, monodevelop

I'm using Monodevelop on OS X to write some basic command line programs. When I run my program the output is sent to a new Terminal window. **How can I have the output sent to a console that's part of MonoDevelop?**

This functionality seems standard as I've used it in Xcode and Visual Studio. I can't find the option in Monodevelop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your project and select the menu:

> Project > YourConsoleProjectsName Options

then select

> Run > General

in the left pane and deselect the checkbox **Run on external console**. Voilà you should now have output in the Application Output window.